# Can I use the Mechromancer's death robot to kill Boll's skags and still get the Man's Best Friends challenge?

Tags: borderlands-2

I just watched the In Memoriam video walkthrough on IGN and in that session the player launched the death robot to deal with the snow skags while Gaige focused on attacking Boll.  That resulted in achieving the Man's Best Friends badass challenge, and I'm wondering if that still works, or if a game patch now considers kills by the death robot as invalidating the challenge.

Comment: Ok, didn't need the death robot.  Ran into Boll's area and awoke him, then ran outside of the entrance and sniped him.  Would like to know if the death robot still works, however.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it should still work for the challenge since the death bot is technically a weapon of yours, so long as it does not hit the snow skags then.

Comment: Actually, that's why I asked, because the challenge is to NOT harm any of the snow skags.  Hence, I thought using the deathtrap robot would automatically void the challenge.